# Does System.IO.File.Move not support previously-defined strings?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, .net, file-manipulation

For example, something like this fails:

```
string oldfile = (@"C:\oldfile.txt");
string newfile = (@"C:\newfolder\newfile.txt");
System.IO.File.Move(oldfile, newfile);
```

Program crashes with **"The given path's format is not supported."**

EDIT: I'm doing this in a Windows Forms project vs. Console project, does that make a difference? Intuitively I wouldn't think it should, but you never know...

Comment: Why do you put parentheses around the string values?

Comment: I can see nothing wrong with the first version. The second is clearly wrong (you'll have \\ in the file names). Can you post a complete console app that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: re: parentheses Oh, heh. Just a dumb mistake on that count... it's late and I was working with some other languages earlier. Thanks for pointing that out though.

Comment: Does the folder "newfolder" exist?

Comment: "The given path's format is not supported." sounds like what VS2010 says about your second code, what does it say when you run the first?

Comment: Also, does it also happen when you run this exact code? You say "something like this", so I presume the real strings are different?

Comment: @Mr Lister Looking into that now, I'll update in a minute.

Comment: *update* Sigh, I'm an idiot. I forgot this was running in a loop and I didn't have a break after the IO.File.Move line, so it was failing because of that. Two lessons learned -- don't debug when tired and don't post questions when tired. Thanks for your replies everybody I really appreciate. I actually learned some things even though the question ended up being erroneous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the mixture of the verbatim string format ( @"..." ) and escaping slashes ( "\" )

The second piece of code

```
string oldFile = @"C:\\oldfile.txt"
```

creates a path of 'C:\\oldfile.txt' which is not recognised as a valid path.

Either use the first version you gave

```
string oldFile = @"C:\oldfile.txt"
```

or

```
string oldFile = "C:\\oldfile.txt"
```

Comment: He said the first version didn't work, so how do you explain that?

Comment: My bad, either I didn't read the question fully or the edits changed the flavour - I thought that it was the second (now missing) paragraph which gave the error.  There is no reason why the code shown should give an error. I tried it out and it works fine.  The message is not from System.IO.File, it looks to be a native win32 message but I didn't chase it down any further than that.

Answer (score 0):

```
string oldfile = (@"C:\oldfile.txt");
string newfile = (@"C:\newfolder\newfile.txt");
System.IO.File.Move(oldfile , newfile );
```

or 
    string oldfile = ("C:\oldfile.txt");
    string newfile = (@"C:\newfolder\newfile.txt");
    System.IO.File.Move(oldfile , newfile );

if the direcotry not exist, create it with Directory.CreateDirectory

Comment: "The given path's format is not supported" is nothing to do with missing directories.

Answer (score 0):

In a string literal prefixed with @ the escape sequences starting with \ are disabled. This is convenient for filepaths since \ is the path separator and you don't want it to start an escape sequence.

You simply have to use the below one:

```
string oldfile = ("C:\\oldfile.txt");
string newfile = ("C:\\newfolder\\newfile.txt");
System.IO.File.Move(oldfile, newfile);
```

**OR**

```
string oldfile = (@"C:\oldfile.txt");
string newfile = (@"C:\newfolder\newfile.txt");
System.IO.File.Move(oldfile, newfile);
```

It works without crash.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this MSDN Article
[MSDN says to use like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx)

```
 string path = @"C:\oldfile.txt";
 string path2 = @"C:\newfolder\newfile.txt";


if (!File.Exists(path)) 
            {
                // This statement ensures that the file is created,
                // but the handle is not kept.
                using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path)) {}
            }
```

Comment: I don't actually think that the parentheses or the variable names would make a difference.

Comment: i am not syaing you to change the variable names, just check the MSDN links, which shows how to use File.Move() .. and i think you have used exactly like that..

Comment: Actually I did read that article earlier and unless I'm totally missing something (which, I probably am) that doesn't work -- using
        if (!File.Exists(path_here))
                        { }
No matter what's in the { } or the path I get 

**Error 1 The name 'File' does not exist in the current context**